# Why does *everything* use a template base class in ATL/WTL?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, atl, wtl

I'm having a lot of trouble understanding the purpose of templates in ATL/WTL code.

When you look at WTL, you see code like:

```
template <class TBase>
class CEditT : public TBase
{
    ...
};

typedef CEditT<ATL::CWindow> CEdit;
```

#### Why is `CEditT` defined with a template base class?

In other words, in what scenario would `CEditT<T>` ever be instantiated where `T` is **not** `CWindow`?

Comment: Maybe to accommodate a case where you want to provide your own Window implementation?

Comment: @Prætorian: How/why/when would you ever want/need/do that though?

Comment: No idea :-). Maybe you have some very fancy skin implemented and want all your windows to have that skin. Also, that's not really CRTP, is it? For it to be [CRTP](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), `CEdit` would be `class CEdit : public Base<CEdit> { ... };`

Comment: @Prætorian: But that  seems really weird for something like CEdit... also, I guess I was thinking of `CWindowImpl` when I wrote "CRTP". I'll remove that, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's so that you can override methods in `ATL::CWindow` that are called by the ATL/WTL class.  If there's something that you don't like in `ATL::CWindow`, you can derive a class from `ATL::CWindow` with overridden methods, and then pass along your new class as `TBase`.

For example, `ATL::CWindow::CenterWindow` for a long while had a bug where it did not properly account for multiple monitors, and I've seen people use this technique to override `CenterWindow` with a fixed implementation.

Comment: +1 for a practical example, thanks. But one question: Isn't that already solvable with a templated *subclass*, though? (e.g. `FixedWindow<CEdit>` rather than `CEditT<FixedWindow>`)

Comment: @Mehrdad: How would `FixedWindow<CEdit>` help if `CEdit` is the thing calling the offending function? Maybe I don't understand exactly what you mean.

Comment: Oooh yeah it wouldn't, my bad. I was thinking of someone else calling the function, not the class itself.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose composition were used instead:

```
template <class TBase> class CEditT {
public:
  TBase base;
  ...
};
```

This is not very different from something like:

```
template <class ITEM> class ListNode {
public:
   ITEM item;
   ListNode<ITEM> *next;
   // ...
};
```

`ListNode` could instead inherit `ITEM`, like `CEditT` does with `TBase`, but the drawback would be that then `ITEM` could not be a basic type like `int`. On the other hand, a `ListNode` would then *be* a kind of `ITEM`, which could be useful. Furthermore, it would have access to any `protected:` parts of `ITEM`.

Comment: I guess my question is, why doesn't it inherit directly from `CWindow` in the first place?

Comment: Good question. That way it is not hard-coded to a particular window class implementation, just like `ListNode` isn't tied to a particular kind of `ITEM`.  You could make your own window implementation, for instance, by customizing the standard one. Derive from it to make `MyWindow` and then you can instantiate `CEditT<MyWindow>`. The question could be reversed: why should we tie a utility class to a particular target class when we can template it and target it to a *kind* of target class that just has the right interface? It's a paradigm. ;)

Comment: In what scenario (practically speaking) would `CEditT<T>` ever be instantiated where `T` is *not* `CWindow`? (Is there any known use case for this?)

Comment: Hmm, good question. Even if there aren't, basically there is no good reaosn not to make `CEditT` be inconsistent with the framework. Someone somewhere is going to want `CEditT<CWindowImpl<MyClass>>` and be in for a rude surprise to find a monolithic `CEdit`.

Comment: Here is a Yahoo groups posting on exactly this subject: http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/wtl/message/5500

Answer (score 1):

It's so that it can take advantage of the [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). If you create a derived class of `CEditT` your definition would be `class CMyEdit : public CEditT<CMyEdit>`. By statically casting its `this` pointer to your class, `CEditT` can call your methods without having to use a vtable.

Comment: When is that actually useful (for `CEditT` and the like)?

Comment: @Mehrdad, a glance at the source for CEditT would probably answer that question. I don't have access to it right now or I'd do it myself. It's quite possible that it uses CRTP only to be consistent with all the other ATL classes.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question.  It's not about CRTP.  This question is about templatizing the *base* class, not the derived class to `static_cast` to.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does *everything* use a template base class in ATL/WTL?

In nutshell, to achieve a *"weird form of compile-time polymorphism"* thanks to a design pattern (rather C++ idiom) one may call *"upside-down inheritance"* as technique to *"specify the base class of a base class"* in order to *"allows you to insert your own classes into the class hierarchy"* to achieve flexibility of specialising types *"without hard-coding implementation to any particular derived class"*.

This all should become clear after reading the excellent article [ATL and Upside-Down Inheritance - Understanding ATL's atypical design approach](https://web.archive.org/web/20010105015500/http://www.devx.com/free/mgznarch/vcdj/1999/julmag99/atlinherit1.asp) written by [Jim Beveridge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/864520/jim-beveridge) and published by Visual C++ Developers Journal in July, 1999. Here is [link to full not paginated copy of the same article](https://web.archive.org/web/20060315072824/http://www.apostate.com/programming/atlupsidedown.html) (also in the Wayback Machine).